# Using two gestureRecognizers continuously without break

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

In my app, i have to implement two UIswipegesturerecognizers (left and right) one after another without removing the finger from screen.
What i have right now is user needs to swipe left and then swipe to right with removing finger .
Is there any idea how i can achieve this without removing my finger.

Thanks,

Comment: (I'm interested if there is a way to simulate the user's finger being removed then put back on again without the user actually doing it... maybe after a swipe left you can set a recognizer to nil or something?)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and track the `.x` value and do the math yourself to figure out if the finger has gone far enough left from the origin (store the origin as a variable) and then far enough right from the origin.

Additionally you could just use `UITouchesMoved` and get the `.x` value of the `touch`.